# How make a div which change height automatically?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a code in cshtml

```
<div id=team-logo-wrapper>
  <ul>
    @foreach (Team team in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <div class="team-section-box">
                <p class="team-name">@team.Name</p>

                <img src="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Images/NBAlogoImg/{0}", team.Path))"
                     class="logo-images" alt="Логотип @team.Name"
                     title="Логотип @team.Name" />

                @Ajax.ActionLink("Открыть статистику",
                    "GetTable",
                    "Home",
                    new { name = team.Name },
                    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = string.Format("result-table-ajax-id-{0}", team.Id), HttpMethod = "POST" },
                    new {  @class = "table-link-ajax", onclick = string.Format("ShowTable({0})", team.Id) }
               )
            </div>
        </li>
    }
  </ul>
</div>
```

and css for `<div id=team-logo-wrapper>`

```
#team-logo-wrapper {
margin: auto;
border: 1px solid #ff0000;
height: 290px;
background-color: rgba(234, 234, 234, 0.64);
margin-top: 50px;
}
```

When i change `height: 290px;` to `height: auto;`, the div don't contain ul, and i have something like that
[image]

How to change CSS style or HTML to make the height with auto changing. Because if i add new team i have to change the height.

Comment: It'd be easier to help if you dumped the output HTML/CSS into a code snippet.

Comment: I don't see a closing `</div>` for your `<div id=team-logo-wrapper>`. Don't you miss it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add display to flex and justify content to center properties to align. Also remove height

Answer (score 0):

I think you use `float`  property on `li` tag. If you use `float` property it need to clearFix.

after ul please put a div like

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

and add style

```
.clear{
 clear:both;
}
```